# How to access url hash/fragment from a Django Request object

Tags: python, django, hash, django-urls, fragment-identifier

As in the title: How can I access the URL hash/fragment (the part following the hash `#`, or 'pound symbol' in US English) from a Django view and so, I suppose, from a Django Request object?

I've not found enough information on the documentation here available: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

P.S. Assume the fragment is included in the URL sent to the server. (I have verified this in my case, where I'm not actually using a browser.)

Comment: While this problem is unsolvable by server-side, it is solvable by client-side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73470437/retrieving-id-atribute-from-url/73470609#comment129745272_73470609

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is not sent to the server, by definition.  From [URI References: Fragment Identifiers on URIs](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html) :

> "The HTTP engine cannot make any assumptions about it.  The server is not even given it."

Comment: This is true, but in my specific case the fragment part is sent to the server (I see it from the apache log).
It's a strange situation, but I know that HTTP requests to that URL will include the fragment part. (It's not a browser to send the request).
So how (if possible) can I access it?

Comment: I realize some user agents (e.g. the version of curl I have installed) send it.  But I think this is clearly a bug.  In fact, this was just fixed in curl CVS (http://curl.haxx.se/cvs.cgi/curl/lib/url.c?r1=1.826&r2=1.827).

Comment: With high probability the node sending the request to that url is in fact using CURL and so your comment is really helpful!
Knowing that CURL has been fixed to not send the fragment anymore is very important and will make me reconsider my approach. Thanks ;)

Comment: The above CVS link rotted, so use this [git one](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/9bd03483ce6983852d41f5f69cb74827c9defc26).