# processing urls with hashes like jsbin

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-urls

jsbin, on browsers which do not support `(window.history && window.history.pushState)` modify the url via `window.location.hash = data.edit;`  ([details here](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/blob/644cdb3673c7fa00d0bdfd6f8aea52809b44e7c9/public/js/chrome/save.js#L260)).

This creates urls like this

```
http://jsbin.com/#/imetor/1/edit
```

How do I get django's urls.py to process a url like that?  [I am not even sure that the hash is being sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181186/how-to-access-url-hash-fragment-from-a-django-request-object).  If it is not being sent to the server, then what is the technique jsbin uses to pass those parameters to the server?

FWIW, this does not work:

```
url(r'^#/(?P<project_id>[0-9A-Za-z]{6,})', 'mysite.views.project_hash', name='project_hash'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The part past the # does not get sent to the server.

In django, if you want to see the url sent to the server, you can do

```
print request.get_full_path()
```

In the case of jsbin, the server returns a page that contains javascript code that then reads the url params and executes code to personalize the page. An example of javascript code that parses a url and executes a function is Backbone.Router (http://backbonejs.org/#Router).