# Retrieving ID atribute from URL

Tags: javascript, django

In my django project i have a url:

```
https://example.com/nice_page#123
```

This url will lead user to particular post on my page, this is an example how it works on stackoverflow:

[What is the "N+1 selects problem" in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping/3298897#3298897) (it is a link to particular answer, and your browser will move you right to this answer.)

My goal is `to get` this `#123` id `from url`.

I can't do it with django's META data by `request.META` it doesn't show this `#123` id, it only returns me `https://example.com/nice_page`

How can i get this `#123` id?
I would prefer making it with django, but javascript is also acceptable.

> Update: as follows from the comments, thanks to –
> Willem Van Onsem and Ankit Tiwari, this task is unsolvable by server-side (by django) [How to access url hash/fragment from a Django Request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181186/how-to-access-url-hash-fragment-from-a-django-request-object)

Comment: The *fragment* (part after the `#`) is *never* send to the server...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, but can i get done it with javascript? How did stackoverflow did it? They got this shiny glowing on their posts which you share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access url hash/fragment from a Django Request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181186/how-to-access-url-hash-fragment-from-a-django-request-object)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari your answer says, it unsolveable by server-side, but i still have client-side, i can do it some how with javascript

Comment: @oruchkin: that is just some css... Nothing at the server side... See the `:target` selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only with JavaScript. E.g. using an example from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash):

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com/nice_page#123');
console.log(url.hash); // Logs: '#123'
```

Or reference the hash of the current URL in a browser:

```js
console.log(window.location.hash);
```

Comment: this is almost what i need, but how do i get `URL` this one is only example, but in reality it is dynamic

Comment: Ah, you could use `window.location.hash` in a browser to get the hash of the current page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

Comment: yes it is, it is solved by only one line of code, marvelous! `console.log(window.location.hash)` it returns `#123` update your answer on this solution, i'll accept you answer

Comment: Sure yeah, added that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use location.search and URLSearchParams.

https://example.com/nice_page?id=123

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = parseInt(params.get("id"));
console.log(id);
```

You can read more about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search

Comment: `params` variable returns an object, yes, but it has no `id`, so in the end it returns NaN

Comment: ahh that is weird I tried in my computer with this URL http://127.0.0.1:5500/nice_page.html?id=123 and it  works.

Comment: i don't have id after question mark, i have it after hash `https://example.com/nice_page#123` but thanks for helping!